# Filtro de Dados no Firebase(Kotlin)

Tags: firebase, kotlin

Fala pessoal Blz? Sou iniciante no Kotlin e no Firebase!

Estou tentando fazer uma busca no firebase em uma coleção que tem dados de tarefas de usuários, eu queria filtrar pelo ID, segue exemplo:

[image: Banco firebase]

Minha busca no momento está assim:

```kotlin
mDatabase.child("TAREFAS_USUARIOS").child(userid)
```

mas desse jeito não vai e não encontro outra maneira na net

Código:

```kotlin
class FrontPage: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mRecyclerView : RecyclerView
    lateinit var mDatabase : DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page)

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        var uid: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        criarNovaTarefa.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, criar_tarefas::class.java))
            finish()
        }

        logRecyclerView()

    }

    private fun logRecyclerView() {

        var uid: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        var userid: String
        userid = uid.uid.toString().trim()


        var FirebaseRecyclerAdapter =  object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<tasks_base,userViewHolder>(
            tasks_base::class.java,
            R.layout.list_view_task,
            userViewHolder::class.java,
            mDatabase.child("TAREFAS_USUARIOS").child(userid)

       ){
           override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: userViewHolder, model: tasks_base, position: Int) {

               viewHolder.itemView.task_title_view.text = model.task_name
               viewHolder.itemView.task_description_view.text = model.task_description
               viewHolder.itemView.task_type_view.text = model.task_type
               viewHolder.itemView.view_task_fim.text = model.finish
               viewHolder.itemView.view_task_inicio.text = model.init
           }

       }
        mRecyclerView.adapter = FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
    }

}
```

Comment: Compartilhe a parte do código em que você recebe o objeto e tenta acessá-lo, e explique melhor qual o problema. Fica difícil ajudar numa pergunta tão genérica

Comment: Oi Rafael! Segue o código

Comment: Por favor, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/446537/edit) a sua pergunta e coloque o código lá :)

Comment: Valeu Rafael, sou novo aqui tb kkkk foi mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera consegui!

Está mais relacionado com a estruturação dos dados do que com a própria "consulta". Troquei o ID do usuário que antes era um valor da chave para o identificador daquela coleção, ou seja, o usuário vai ter o ID dele e dentro do ID dele vão ter vários outros IDs que se referem as atividades dele.